# How to force a multilayered math environment to column width

Tags: math-mode, breqn, column-width

I have a multilayered math environment in a two column article. The equations go past the column width. How do I avoid that? Below is my MWE.

P.S. I've loaded the breqn package, but I don't know how to use it in this context.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

%================%
%  New Commands  %
%================%
% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\fb}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\ub}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\chib}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}\label{eq:unscented_problem_formulation}
    \xb_i := (x_i,y_i,h_i,v_i,\gamma_i,\sigma_i,\phi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^7 \qquad 
    \ub := (u_\phi,u_L) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad \\
    \chib_i \in supp(\varepsilon_T,\phi_T) \qquad
    \forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi \\  
    \begin{array}{l l}
        \textsf{Min}   
        & J[\xb(\cdot),t_f] := \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\left[(\gamma_i(t_f) - \overline{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \overline{\sigma}_f)^2\right] \\
        \textsf{s.t.} 
        & \dot{\xb}_1 = \fb(\xb_1,\ub,t) \\
        & \vdots \\
        & \dot{\xb}_{N_\chi} = \fb(\xb_{N_\chi},\ub,t) \\
        &\xb_i(t_0) = (0\text{ m},0\text{ m},1\text{ m},1\text{ m/s},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad}) \qquad \forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi. \\
        & (t_0,t_f) = (0,1) \text{ s} \\
        & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\gamma_i(t_f) = \overline{\gamma}_f = 0 \\
        & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\sigma_i(t_f) = \overline{\sigma}_f = 0 \\
        & u_\phi \in [-4\pi,4\pi] \text{ rad} \\
        & u_L    \in [-10000,10000] \text{ N} \\
        & \varepsilon_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{N}(0.001,0.001^2) \text{ rad} \\
        & \phi_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{U}[0,2\pi] \text{ rad} 
    \end{array}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a useful purpose is served by enclosing all math terms at hand in a single `gather*` environment. I suggest inserting a line break before `\forall\ i=1,\dots,N_{\chi}` to make the material fit inside the width of a column. Do yourself a favor and load the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, to gain access to its `\unit` and `\qty` statements. And, since the document employs a Times Roman text font clone, you might was well load the `newtxtmath` package to get a math font that matches the text font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} % Times Roman clone text and math fonts
\DeclareMathOperator{\rad}{rad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for \qty and \unit macros
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\newcommand{\fb}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\ub}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\chib}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}%  \label{eq:unscented_problem_formulation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\xb_i \coloneqq (x_i,y_i,h_i,v_i,\gamma_i,\sigma_i,\phi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^7 \\ 
    &\ub \coloneqq (u_\phi,u_L) \in \mathbb{R}^2  \\
    &\chib_i \in \supp(\varepsilon_T,\phi_T) \quad
    \forall\,i=1,\dots,N_{\chi} 
\end{aligned} \\[\jot]
\textsf{Min}\, J[\xb(\cdot),t_f] 
  \coloneqq \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}}w_i
  \bigl[(\gamma_i(t_f) - \bar{\gamma}_f)^2 
    + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \bar{\sigma}_f)^2 \bigr]
\end{gather*}
such that
\[
\begin{aligned}
    &\dot{\xb}_1 = \fb(\xb_1,\ub,t) \\
    &\,\,\vdots \\
    &\dot{\xb}_{N_{\chi}} = \fb(\xb_{N_{\chi}},\ub,t) \\
    &\xb_i(t_0) = (\qty{0}{\meter},\qty{0}{\meter},\qty{1}{\meter}, 
                   \qty{1}{\meter\per\second}, \qty{0}{\rad}, 
                   \qty{0}{\rad}, \qty{0}{\rad}) \\
    &\qquad\qquad \forall\ i=1,\dots,N_{\chi}. \\
    &(t_0,t_f) = (\qty{0}{\second},\qty{1}{\second}) \\
    &\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}} w_i\gamma_i(t_f) 
        = \bar{\gamma}_f = 0 \\[\jot]
    &\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{N_{\chi}} w_i\sigma_i(t_f) 
        = \bar{\sigma}_f = 0 \\
    &u_\phi \in [-4\pi,4\pi]\,\unit{\rad} \\
    &u_L    \in [-10000,10000]\, \unit{\newton} \\
    &\varepsilon_T \sim \mathcal{N}(0.001,0.001^2)\,\unit{\rad} \\
    &\phi_T \sim \mathcal{U}[0,2\pi]\,\unit{\rad}
\end{aligned}
\]

\lipsum % filler text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to keep the original formatting to be consistent with the rest of the paper (sorry I didn't mention that before). I took a clue from both Mico and Celdor and broke up the long expression by adding another row in the array environment. My modified code is below:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

%================%
%  New Commands  %
%================%
% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\fb}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\ub}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\chib}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}\label{eq:unscented_problem_formulation}
\xb_i := (x_i,y_i,h_i,v_i,\gamma_i,\sigma_i,\phi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^7 \qquad 
\ub := (u_\phi,u_L) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \qquad \\
\chib_i \in supp(\varepsilon_T,\phi_T) \qquad
\forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi \\  
\begin{array}{l l}
    \textsf{Min}   
    & J[\xb(\cdot),t_f] := \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\left[(\gamma_i(t_f) - \overline{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \overline{\sigma}_f)^2\right] \\
    \textsf{s.t.} 
    & \dot{\xb}_1 = \fb(\xb_1,\ub,t) \\
    & \vdots \\
    & \dot{\xb}_{N_\chi} = \fb(\xb_{N_\chi},\ub,t) \\
    & \xb_i(t_0) = (0\text{ m},0\text{ m},1\text{ m},1\text{ m/s},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad}) 
    & \qquad \forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi. \\
    & (t_0,t_f) = (0,1) \text{ s} \\
    & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\gamma_i(t_f) = \overline{\gamma}_f = 0 \\
    & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\sigma_i(t_f) = \overline{\sigma}_f = 0 \\
    & u_\phi \in [-4\pi,4\pi] \text{ rad} \\
    & u_L    \in [-10000,10000] \text{ N} \\
    & \varepsilon_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{N}(0.001,0.001^2) \text{ rad} \\
    & \phi_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{U}[0,2\pi] \text{ rad} 
\end{array}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to format this long expression.

I'd like to point out LaTeX has plenty of math environments including their inner variants, which you can nest, which let you format and organise very complex expressions. It's all explained in the documentation of the package [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). I would also recommend reading documentation of [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), which loads [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and adds many improvements and additional solutions.

The code

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% ================%
% New Commands  %
% ================%
% Bold math variables
\newcommand{\fb}{\mathbf{f}}
\newcommand{\xb}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\ub}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\chib}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}

\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{aligned}
    & \xb_i := (x_i,y_i,h_i,v_i,\gamma_i,\sigma_i,\phi_i) \in \mathbb{R}^7 \\
    & \ub := (u_\phi,u_L) \in \mathbb{R}^2
  \end{aligned} \\
  \chib_i \in \operatorname{supp}(\varepsilon_T,\phi_T, \ i=1,\dots,N_\chi \\
  \begin{aligned}
    & \operatorname{Min} J[\xb(\cdot),t_f :={} \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i \bigl[ (\gamma_i(t_f) - \overline{\gamma}_f)^2 + (\sigma_i(t_f) - \overline{\sigma}_f)^2 \bigr] \\
    & \footnotesize
      \qquad\textsf{s.t.}\ \begin{aligned}[t]
                             & \dot{\xb}_1 = \fb(\xb_1,\ub,t) \\
                             & \vdots \\
                             & \dot{\xb}_{N_\chi} = \fb(\xb_{N_\chi},\ub,t) \\
                             & xb_i(t_0) = (0\text{ m},0\text{ m},1\text{ m},1\text{ m/s},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad},0\text{ rad}) \\
                             & \qquad\forall\,i=1,\dots,N_\chi. \\
                             & (t_0,t_f) = (0,1) \text{ s} \\
                             & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\gamma_i(t_f) = \overline{\gamma}_f = 0 \\
                             & \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N_\chi}w_i\sigma_i(t_f) = \overline{\sigma}_f = 0 \\
                             & u_\phi \in [-4\pi,4\pi] \text{ rad} \\
                             & u_L    \in [-10000,10000] \text{ N} \\
                             & \varepsilon_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{N}(0.001,0.001^2) \text{ rad} \\
                             & \phi_T\, \sim\, \mathcal{U}[0,2\pi] \text{ rad} 
                           \end{aligned}
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\kant[2-5]
\end{document}
```

and screenshot

[image]